# About adding a linked server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Here is the sql that i did run.

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver TestServer,
 'Index Server',
 'MSIDXS',
 'MyCatalogueMachine.MyTestCatalogue'
```

Where `MyCatalogueMachine` is the name of machine where i have created my indexing service catalogue `MyTestCatalogue`.

It created the linked server `TestServer` . Then i run the sql query as:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(TestServer,
        'SELECT filename,size FROM SCOPE() WHERE CONTAINS(Contents,''"test*"'')'
) AS Q
```

But it returns an error message as:

> OLE DB provider "MSIDXS" for linked
>   server "TestServer" returned message
>   "Service is not running. ". Msg 7320,
>   Level 16, State 2, Line 5 Cannot
>   execute the query "SELECT
>   filename,size FROM SCOPE()WHERE
>   CONTAINS(Contents,'"test*"')" against
>   OLE DB provider "MSIDXS" for linked
>   server "TestServer".

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Is SQL Server actually running on the server you are trying to link to?

Have you tried connecting to the server via Management Studio?  If you aren't able to do that, try opening Services.msc from the Run command and connecting to the server, make sure the "Sql Server" service is started.

Comment: No, my sql server and catalogs are in different machines. i am able to connect to the sql server through management studio.

Comment: What I mean is, the linked server that you are connecting to, have you made sure that SQL Server is running on it?  When you connect via Management Studio does it have a green icon next to the Server name?  If it has a red icon, you need to start the SQL Server, just right click on it in Management Studio and select Start.

Comment: Yes. It is running. Is it necessary to have a sql server on the machine where i created the catalog?

Comment: Have you made sure the SQL Browser service on the linked server is running as gbn suggested?

Comment: After adding the linked server, i have tested the connection to the linked server and it given the success message.

Answer (score 0):

"Service is not running."?

Either: The full text service (CONTAINS) isn't installed or not running...

Or: SQL browser service isn't running